# Must I accept Canadian funds if I do business in Canada

Tags: canada, legal-tender

I'd like to sell a product in Vancouver, Canada. If the company is Canadian, must I accept Canadian dollars? If my company is not incorporated in Canada, does anything change ? Can I sell a product to an individual in Canada if my company is not incorporated in Canada and not registered to operate in my province ? The product is $1500 per unit, advertised on a website.

Comment: How are you accepting money? I just made a payment for software, just a token amount, and I made the payment in Euros. I didn't give it much thought, but that's because the interface was through PayPal and was pretty transparent.

Answer (score 4):

As long as you don't finance and the payment is upfront, its up to you and your customer how to pay. If you provide the product **before** the payment is being made or finance in any way (i.e.: there's debt), then the Canadian dollar, being [legal tender in Canada](http://laws-lois.justice.gc.ca/eng/acts/C-52/page-1.html), **must** be accepted.

Considering the large amount, you would probably not be accepting cash anyway, so the point is moot. How they pay their credit cards is not your problem. However, do take into the account the currency exchange rates and fees that add costs to purchasing your product.

If you don't have any physical presence (i.e.: online store only, no physical location on Canadian soil), then it goes by the rules of the jurisdiction where you've incorporated.

Check with the local legal professional to be sure.